# Parsing an html line and pulling out only numbers that meet a certain criteria

Tags: python, parsing

I am using line.rfind to parse a particular line of html code. For example, this is the line of html code I am parsing:

```
<strong class="temp">79<span>&deg;</span></strong><span class="low"><span>Lo</span> 56<span>&deg;</span></span>
```

and this is the code I use to split the line to (in this case) pull out the '79'.

```
position0 = line.rfind('{}'.format(date1.strftime("%a")))
if position0 > 0 :
        self.high0 = lines[line_number + 4].split('<span>')[0].split('">')[-1]
```

Now I need to only pull out that number if it is >=94 and <=37. If it does not meet this criteria, I don't want anything to happen. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

```
if int(c.high0) >= 34:
            plt.text(x, y, int(c.high0), fontsize=7, fontweight='bold')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I would use a regex to obtain the high temperature.  Either that or maybe beautifulsoup if I was parsing a lengthy Html document.  The following should grab all the high temps from a string that repeats the pattern listed in the OP.

```
import re

s = '<strong class="temp">79<span>&deg;</span></strong><span class="low"><span>Lo</span> 56<span>&deg;</span></span>'
p = re.compile(r'>(?P<high>\d+)<span>\&deg')
matches = p.finditer(s)
for match in matches:
    print match.group('high')
```

Comment: jbiz - I am only doing this for one particular city and it is just for my personal use, so this quick and dirty way will work for my purposes. Otherwise, I would definitely look into using BeautifulSoup.

It looks like what you suggested will still retrieve the high no matter what the temperature is. All I need to do is figure out a way to only retrieve the high if it meets the criteria I mentioned above.